# How to extract just the first line of multiline string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using split() to parse till a colon. I have several colons in my text but I just need the string from the first line. What i need to do to just get the first line?

```
line = """Hello : 
          This is a test ......:

          Testpath: C:\\...
          blablablabla
          123:"""

if ' :' in line: 
  av = line.split(" :",1)[0]
  print av
```

Is it possible to access the first line without using regexpression??

Comment: Post the output you are getting and what you want it to be.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, and you are not using a regular expression. I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 7):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to print only the first line of the multi-lined string irrespective of colon as separator. If this is the case, here is my possible solution (for windows os):

```
line = """ bravo cos
        daring in the blah blah."""
```

The soln is:

```
print(line.split("\n")[0])
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first line you might want to use `splitlines`

If I understood well your question, this code might help you.

```
line = """Hello : 
      This is a test ......:

      Testpath: C:\\...
      blablablabla
      123:"""

first, *others = line.splitlines()
```

`first` will contain the first line, `others` will contian a list of other lines

NB: You are not using any regex